# How to fetch a jar from the central repository to the local repository without building a maven project or writting a pom file?

Tags: maven, plugins

How to use the command 'mvn' to fetch a jar from the central repository to the local repository without building a maven project or writting a pom file?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Eq. I fetch a jar from the central repository to the local repository, then i can copy it from the local repository and use it in a none-maven-style project. I don't want to download it on a website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dependency:get](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) goal of [Maven Dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to do that.

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:get -DrepoUrl=<repo URL> -Dartifact=<group>:<artifact>:<version>
```

Sample:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:get -DrepoUrl=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 -Dartifact=com.yammer.metrics:metrics-spring:2.1.5
```